# Deployment of lightning components using eclipse

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-experience, aura-attribute, aura-id

I have tried moving lightning components and applcn from one sandbox to other. using option deploy to server but it fails. I have added package.xml file


    
        *
        AuraDefinitionBundle
    
    35.0

**but also it shows error
   File Name:    aura/SCC_PolicyDetails/SCC_PolicyDetails.cmp
   Full Name:  SCC_PolicyDetails
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Invalid definition for null:SCC_MemberPolicyInfoDetails: null**

can anyone suggests exact way. I am strucked and never before on lightning.

Comment: In stackexchange i have gone through different posts but it shows to deploy using ANT migration tool or mavenmate. but i dont have idea  how to use them. instead please guide how to deploy using eclipse

Comment: It's very easy to deploy Lightning Applications/Components via change set.  
Create Change Set > Add Components > Select 'Lightning Component Bundle' > Add ...
and you know the drill [upload/validate/deploy]
If you have the possibility to deploy via change set, please opt for it.

Comment: it shows dependencies also.  i need add them as well right. i dont know which to select or simply select all . does it gives problem

Comment: No, it does not show dependencies. You may check the code to find dependencies. Or if you do not have many Lightning Component Bundles in that Sandbox and it's not risky to deploy all, you may do so as well.

Comment: There are 30 to 40 components are there. If i choose one component when i hit dependencies it showing like 25 items.

Comment: Then I guess you should take them all.

Comment: can you share please your package.xml file

Comment: <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>. I already added in package XML file